# Personalise the stem function on matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, vibration

I am writing a code on matlab for an exercise to draw the mode shape of a system. The picture I get I think is ok, but I want to be able to change color and make the line thicker. 
This is my code:

```
    clear all
close all 
clc
%% Assignment 3

% X Direction
% Natural Frequencies and Damping Ratios
wn_X1=354.3; d_X1=0.038;
wn_X2=467.6; d_X2=0.049;

% Damped Frequencies
wd_X1=wn_X1*sqrt(1-(d_X1)^2);
wd_X2=wn_X2*sqrt(1-(d_X2)^2);

% Residues in X direction
sX1_11=1.9890*10^-6; nuX1_11=-1.9644*10^-5;
sX2_11=1.4978*10^-5; nuX2_11=-4.4070*10^-5;
sX1_12=-4.4952*10^-6; nuX1_12=-1.2556*10^-5;
sX2_12=7.0287*10^-6; nuX2_12=-3.3470*10^-5;


alphaX11_1=2*(d_X1*wn_X1*sX1_11-wd_X1*nuX1_11);
alphaX12_1=2*(d_X1*wn_X1*sX1_12-wd_X1*nuX1_12);
alphaX11_2=2*(d_X2*wn_X2*sX2_11-wd_X2*nuX2_11);
alphaX12_2=2*(d_X2*wn_X2*sX2_12-wd_X2*nuX2_12);

betaX11_1=2*sX1_11;
betaX12_1=2*sX1_12;
betaX11_2=2*sX2_11;
betaX12_2=2*sX2_12;

% Complex modal matrix in X direction
sX1=wd_X1*1j; sX2=wd_X2*1j;
u_11=sqrt(alphaX11_1+betaX11_1*sX1);
u_21=sqrt(alphaX12_1+betaX12_1*sX1);
u_12=sqrt(alphaX11_2+betaX11_2*sX2);
u_22=sqrt(alphaX12_2+betaX12_2*sX2);

U=[u_11 u_12; u_21 u_22]

% Y Direction
% Natural Frequencies and Damping Ratios
wn_Y1=225.6; d_Y1=0.038;
wn_Y2=386.6; d_Y2=0.049;

% Damped Frequencies
wd_Y1=wn_Y1*sqrt(1-(d_Y1)^2);
wd_Y2=wn_Y2*sqrt(1-(d_Y2)^2);

% Residues in X direction
sY1_11=8.5993*10^-6; nuY1_11=-1.5280*10^-5;
sY2_11=1.4732*10^-5; nuY2_11=-4.9648*10^-5;
sY1_12=4.0081*10^-6; nuY1_12=-1.0945*10^-5;
sY2_12=4.4653*10^-6; nuY2_12=-3.3297*10^-5;


alphaY11_1=2*(d_Y1*wn_Y1*sY1_11-wd_Y1*nuY1_11);
alphaY12_1=2*(d_Y1*wn_Y1*sY1_12-wd_Y1*nuY1_12);
alphaY11_2=2*(d_Y2*wn_Y2*sY2_11-wd_Y2*nuY2_11);
alphaY12_2=2*(d_Y2*wn_Y2*sY2_12-wd_Y2*nuY2_12);

betaY11_1=2*sX1_11;
betaY12_1=2*sX1_12;
betaY11_2=2*sX2_11;
betaY12_2=2*sX2_12;

% Complex modal matrix in X direction
sY1=wd_Y1*1j; sY2=wd_Y2*1j;
v_11=sqrt(alphaY11_1+betaY11_1*sY1);
v_21=sqrt(alphaY12_1+betaY12_1*sY1);
v_12=sqrt(alphaY11_2+betaY11_2*sY2);
v_22=sqrt(alphaY12_2+betaY12_2*sY2);

V=[v_11 v_12; v_21 v_22]

% Plot mode shapes in X Direction
UU=real(U);
omegaX=[wn_X1 wn_X2];
subplot(2,1,1)
plot(UU,'--');
xlabel('Elements','FontSize',25); ylabel('Mode amplitude','FontSize',25); 
title(['Mode shapes in X direction, \omega=' sprintf('%4.2f, ',omegaX)],'FontSize',25);
axis([0.5 2.5 -0.2 0.3]);
set(gca,'XTick',[1:2],'FontSize',20);
Leg=legend('Mode 1','Mode 2');
set(Leg,'FontSize',25);
hold on
stem(UU,'filled','MarkerSize',11);
hold on

% Plot mode shapes in Y Direction
VV=real(V);
omegaY=[wn_Y1 wn_Y2];
subplot(2,1,2)
plot(VV,'--');
xlabel('Elements','FontSize',25); ylabel('Mode amplitude','FontSize',25); 
title(['Mode shapes in Y direction, \omega=' sprintf('%4.2f, ',omegaY)],'FontSize',25);
axis([0.5 2.5 -0.2 0.3]);
set(gca,'XTick',[1:2],'FontSize',20);
Leg=legend('Mode 1','Mode 2');
set(Leg,'FontSize',25);
hold on
stem(VV,'filled','MarkerSize',11);
hold on
```

The code is runable, I just want the plot to look a bit nicer. 
Cheers guys 
D

Comment: `plot` lets you specify colors, linewidth, etc: [MATLAB plot doc](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot.html#namevaluepairarguments) ...
Same for `stem`: [MATLAB stem doc](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/stem.html#namevaluepairarguments)

Comment: if i specify 'b', I get all 4 dots in blue, but I want the dots for Mode 1 in blue and the one for Mode 2 in green.

Comment: What does the `U` and `V` matrices represent?  I see you're plotting the entire matrix, and the way matrices are plot is done on a column basis.  Each column gets a separate colour.

Comment: U and V are my complex modal matrices (it's a vibration problem where I have to calculate the modal matrices then plot the mode shapes). To plot the mode shapes I take the real part of the modal matrices. How do I assign a coulour to each column tho in the plot lines?

Comment: Use a separate plot command for each column/color.

Comment: ok i think it works, I created a new line to plot stem for each column on the same graph seperately. Thanks uys

Answer (score 0):

I created a different command for each column like Geoff suggested